# Js Button SDK add custom values and webhook response

Tags: button, paypal, sdk, subscription

I have react button to create Subscription, but I need a way to link the subscription (when completed) to an ID (let's say Discord), so in my backend I can correlate the two.

Do webhook data retain the custom field from the client button?

```
  const createSubscription = (data, actions, guildId, userId) => {
    return actions.subscription.create({
      plan_id: 'PLAN_ID',
      custom_id: guildId,
      userId: userId
    });
  };

return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider>
      <PayPalButtons
        createSubscription={() => createSubscription(data, actions, guildId, userId)}
        style={{
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          label: 'paypal'
      }}
      />
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
```

Tried the sandbox webhook, but could not simulate a custom payment with said custom fields

Answer (score 0):

See the [create subscription API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create) for values that might be recognized and returned, mainly `custom_id`. Any field not listed in the API reference will be ignored.